# Maximum Value From Python Contour Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a 2D contour plot in python, starting with 2D arrays of x-axis values and their corresponding z-axis values - each of these 2D arrays correspond to a different value on the y-axis. I am wondering if there is a command which allows me to obtain the value of y where intensity (z axis) is greatest for a given value of x? Matplotlib was used to produce the contour plot. Any he[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiC5R.png)lp is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify:  Are you trying to read the value off the plot, e.g. via mouse-over text, or are you trying to define a function which will run against the data structure without necessarily involving human eyes on the plot?

Comment: We would like to produce a 2D array of micrometer position (y-axis) and intensity (z-axis) for a given wavelength (x-axis). Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you looking for advice on writing a function, or advice on plotting the results of a function you already have?
Your comment sounds like you're looking for a function f(x) -> (y, z), but your original question sounds like you're looking for a function f(x, z) -> y.  If you are looking for either of those, the "contour plot" and "matplotlib" portions of your question are irrelevant.  Instead include whether you're using numpy or some other package to do the computations.
If you already have the data you need, and are just trying to display it to users, describe the image you want.